# Is it OK to uninstall XCode after using it to update Python version on terminal through Homebrew?

Tags: python-3.x, xcode, homebrew

I don't use XCode and it takes a lot of space .. wondering if its OK to delete it after downloading it for Homebrew to update the latest Python on the Terminal.

Comment: You can install Python using the installer: https://www.python.org/downloads/
How to uninstall Homebrew: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew

Answer (score 0):

You won't need Xcode to use Homebrew, but some of the software and components you'll want to install using brew will rely on Xcode's Command Line Tools package.

You should leave it installed but you can also delete it and download it again when you need it.
I would recommend you to leave it installed and maybe get an extension for your storage.